# Django Wagtail sitemap

Tags: django, wagtail

I have an existing Django site for which i've added [Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/). I would like to have a sitemap for both Django and Wagtail urls.

My current `sitemap.py`:

```py
class StaticSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = "weekly"
    protocol = "https"

    def items(self):
        return ["public:index", "other pages etc..."]

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

My current `urls.py`:

```py
sitemaps = {"static": StaticSitemap}
path(
    "sitemap.xml",
    sitemap,
    {"sitemaps": sitemaps},
    name="django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap",
),
```

The above works correctly for a standard Django sitemap. How do I include Wagtail urls?

Comment: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681046/how-to-join-wagtail-and-django-sitemaps

Comment: Thanks but i've already tried the answer you've linked to and it does not work. Perhaps that only worked on older versions of wagtail. Do you have a currently working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your sitemap view comes from `wagtail.contrib.sitemaps.views` (if you're using Django's view, you should switch to Wagtail's.

Then the only thing you need to do is add Wagtail's Sitemap on your sitemaps dictionary:

```py
from wagtail.contrib.sitemaps.sitemap_generator import Sitemap

sitemaps = {"static": StaticSitemap, "wagtail": Sitemap}
```